# Is this relation between Wirtinger operators and gradient correct?

Tags: complex-analysis

Is that correct that for all $f,g$ that are $\mathcal C^2$ we have $\nabla f\nabla g=2(\partial f\bar\partial g+\bar\partial f\partial g)$ where $\partial$ and $\bar\partial$ are the Wirtinger operators?

I came up with this relation while playing with the Laplacian operator but I am not fully convinced it is correct.

If it is, does it came from a more fundamental relation or is it pure calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\p{\partial}
\def\pc{\overline{\partial}}$We have
\begin{align*}
\nabla f\cdot\nabla g &= \p_x f\p_x g+\p_y f\p_y g\\
&= (\p f+\pc f)(\p g+\pc g) + i(\p f-\pc f)i(\p g-\pc g) \\
&= \p f\p g + \p f \pc g + \pc f \p g + \pc f\pc g \\
&\quad -(\p f\p g - \p f \pc g - \pc f \p g + \pc f\pc g) \\
&= 2(\p f\pc g + \pc f\p g),
\end{align*}
as claimed.
This comes directly from the definition of the Wirtinger derivative.